# SmartGWT loading WSDL

Tags: web-services, wsdl, smartgwt

I am trying to call a web service from my SmartGWT program by coding on server side.
However the `XMLTools.LoadWSDL(WSDLurl,WSDLLoadCallback)` is giving me an error for the following code:

CODE :

```
XMLTools.loadWSDL("http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL",new WSDLLoadCallback(){

        //@Override
        public void execute(WebService webService) {
            System.out.println("********************In XMLTools");
            temp = webService;
        }               
      });
```

ERROR :

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.smartgwt.client.data.XMLTools.loadWSDL(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/smartgwt/client/data/WSDLLoadCallback;

What would be the cause and possible solution for the same?

Thanks!